# Is it possible to shave head before departing for Hajj

Tags: hajj, umrah, shaving, mecca

I am leaving for Umrah soon, but due to the uncleanliness of barbers in Mecca, I am wondering if I am able to shave my head beforehand and still have it count?

Comment: you can shave your head beforehand and after doing umra, just do the shaving yourself with a razor. I think you still need to shave your head after umra even if you don't have any hairs.

Comment: Note that "the uncleanliness of barbers in Mecca" is an accusation which may be correct for some people and wrong for others and sounds like ghaibah. To complete 'umrah you need to shave your head or shorten your hair. So whether you do it before is up to you, but you must have some hair on your head afterwards to fullfil this duty.

Answer (score 1):

It's better you don't cut your scalp hair in such a manner that sufficient hair is not available for cutting/shaving, crop cut look is better to be avoided before embarking. Cutting of scalp hair or shaving is a pillar of umrah and hajj. It needs to be acted upon.

> “having your heads shaved(hair cut alternatively)” [al-Fath 48:27].

Secondly shaving is not compulsory it's recommended, you can cut your hair equally using a personal electric trimmer.

The reward for shaving is thrice when compared to cutting while doing pilgrimage. Lesser(umrah) or major (hajj).

> the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) shaved his entire head, and he prayed for those who shaved their heads three times, and for those who cut their hair once.
>
> al-Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah (18/98).

For fear of unclean barbers, Rely on Allah , recite remembrances of morning and evening to protect oneself. If you are going to avail their paid services.

PS: Hajj e tamattu is kind of hajj where you perform umrah on arrival in mecca and remove ihram and reenter it just before hajj. Many scholars will recommend hajj tamattu  for an individual if one has sufficient finances instead of random umrah.